# Retrieving data ( Balance sheets not stocks) from yahoo finance with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, finance, yahoo-api

I try for few days to get Balance sheet data from yahoo finance with VBA instruction like ".getElementsByTagName" for companies but it's not working... nothing occuring, I am stuck...

Any ideas ? see code below :

```
Sub Get_Data()
Dim url As String
Dim http As Object
Dim TR_col As Object, Tr As Object
Dim TD_col As Object, Td As Object
Dim row As Long, col As Long
Dim html As Object
Dim tbl As Object
'

On Error Resume Next

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") 'CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    url = "https//finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/balance-sheet?p=AAPL"
    http.Open "POST", url, False
    http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    http.Send
    MsgBox http.responseText

Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
Set tbl = html.getElementById("Pos(r)")

    row = 1
    col = 1
    Set TR_col = html.getElementsByTagName("TR")
    For Each Tr In TR_col
        Set TD_col = Tr.getElementsByTagName("TD")
        For Each Td In TD_col
            Cells(row, col) = Td.innerText
            col = col + 1
        Next
        col = 1
        row = row + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: The first step in debugging your code is to stop ignoring the errors.  Also, using early binding so you can have intellisense would also be useful this stage.

Comment: Having said that, you should also know that Yahoo finance changes the format of its pages from time to time, so if you are going to use that as your source, you will need to become adept at adapting to the various changes. A number of people here have been recently reporting difficulty with yahoo finance. You should research that and perhaps adapt some of the solutions to your problem.

Comment: @ Ron Rosenfeld. Thanks for the hint Ron, Indeed, I forgot to remove "On error resume next" ( Beginner's mistake ;-) For your second comment, I know that yahoo change its format time to time and I am ok with this. I have successfully retrieve stocks data. However, for financial statements it's another story...

Comment: In addition, I have also modified the URL link which was not working too... So I get the right Yahoo finance page ( In this example APPLE Financial Statements) but it does not retrieve any data at all...

Comment: Try using `GET` instead of `POST`.  Also, I recently ran across [this free api for company financials](https://financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs/) which returns a JSON document, and may be easier to parse and maintain.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ron, it is indeed a great tool ! But I am afraid I cannot rely on as I develop this for my employer and I need to master the sourcing from A to Z

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202130/discussion-between-lb2019-and-ron-rosenfeld).

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick.  I had to add ':' to the URL, changed 'POST' to 'GET' and set 2 request headers, the first is a cookie, which I think will expire in a year's time, this was found out by running the following:

```
Cells(1, 1) = http.responseText
Dim responseHeader As String
responseHeader = http.getAllResponseHeaders
Cells(2, 1) = responseHeader
```

and reading the setcookie line. I then simply hardcoded that into the request header. Running code is as follows:

```
Sub Get_Data()
Dim url As String
Dim http As Object
Dim TR_col As Object, Tr As Object
Dim TD_col As Object, Td As Object
Dim row As Long, col As Long
Dim html As Object
Dim tbl As Object

'On Error Resume Next

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") 
'CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
url = "https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/balance-sheet?p=aapl"
http.Open "GET", url, False
http.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "B=22guonpesgnqg&b=3&s=5p"
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
http.Send
Cells(1, 1) = http.responseText
'Dim responseHeader As String
'responseHeader = http.getAllResponseHeaders
'Cells(2, 1) = responseHeader

Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
Set tbl = html.getElementById("Pos(r)")
row = 1
col = 1
Set TR_col = html.getElementsByTagName("TR")
For Each Tr In TR_col
    Set TD_col = Tr.getElementsByTagName("TD")
    For Each Td In TD_col
        Cells(row, col) = Td.innerText
        col = col + 1
    Next
    col = 1
    row = row + 1
Next

End Sub
```

Hopefully that is what you wanted, the returned data looks similar to what my browser shows.

Comment: Many thanks mx5_craig, however it seems that I cannot still retrieve data from it, ( like Balance sheets figures) i think it is maybe I don't target the right table in the webpage...

Comment: It return well data only in cell A1. But the loop after is not working as the tag name TR is empty...

Comment: Possibly you need to generate your own cookie, using the method I describe.  This code for me returns with 38 rows of data, columns A-E filled in.

Comment: I can confirm that running this code on a different PC as posted above did not work, just returned a cookie disclaimer.  Generating a new cookie, (comment out the setRequestHeader "cookie" line) and uncomment the 3 lines below, copy the cookie string and hardcode that in.  Then it should work!

Comment: I think maybe I know where it could com from.... You are using Yahoo UK, I am using Yahoo Canada, for me the link is this one : <http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/balance-sheet?p=aapl> do you think it can be the issue ? cause it seems there is no cookie implemented...